# When can NoSuchResult be thrown

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have inherited a system with a rather wierd bug that occurs maybe once every 6 months, where the application suddenly loses track of Database data.

The system has redundancy with 2 servers that are scheduled to run the same function at the same time. They both get the same input data to the function and they both talk to the same postgres database, however the behaviours is different on the 2 machines.

The function that is being executed is calling the database and checking if there is a row with the specified id as supplied by the input parameter and if there is it executes `A()`, otherwise `B()`

Problem is that one server executes `A()` and the other `B()`. I have searched everywhere and there is no code writing to this table or deleting from it. So within all reason I think that they should both execute the same code.

This is the code that is fetching from the database:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "backend-persistence")
private EntityManager em;
public Optional<OfferEntity> getOfferFromOfferId(final long offerId, final String countryAlias, final String langauageAlias) {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<OfferEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(OfferEntity.class);
    Root<OfferEntity> from = cq.from(OfferEntity.class);
    cq.select(from);
    cq.where(cb.and(cb.equal(from.get(OfferEntity_.offerId), offerId),
            cb.equal(from.get(OfferEntity_.country), countryAlias),
            cb.equal(from.get(OfferEntity_.language), langauageAlias)));

    try {

        return Optional.of(em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult());
    } catch (NoResultException nre) {

        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

And I am getting an empty optional from one of the servers but not the other.

So I guess as a tl;dr, am I missunderstanding NoResultException and in what concrete situations can this be thrown? besides if there are no rows matching the query.

Comment: http://www.datanucleus.org/javadocs/javax.persistence/2.2/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult--

Comment: @DN1 I am very well aware of it, but define "if there is no result". I think it is rather ambigous as I can be "no rows matching the query" or "the database threw an error, so there is no result" or possibly something else

Comment: There's nothing ambiguous about it. The fact that JPA treats the missing result from `getSingleResult` as an exceptional condition stems from the fact that it is *meant* to be used with queries that necessarily yield **exactly** one result (e.g. aggregate queries). A query that 'according to my business logic should probably never have more than one result' is not a good candidate for `getSingleResult`, you should really use `getResultList` with those.

Comment: I am assuming that `getResultList` should have been used in this case as it might return either one or zero results?

Comment: Different library versions come to mind.

Comment: Yes. That being said, `NoResultException` is certainly not meant to represent the condition in which the database threw an exception. What you're experiencing might be a bug with the JDBC driver for Postgres, or maybe (which I think is less likely) a cache misconfiguration.

Comment: If the database had a problem then I'd expect PersistenceException. But either way, you should have the root cause (SQLException) as the nested cause exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use getSingleResult() when you are sure that you will get exactly one result. In all other cases you have to use getResultList()

From the API doc of javax.persistence.Query getSingleResult():

```
java.lang.Object getSingleResult()

Execute a SELECT query that returns a single untyped result.

Returns:
the result

Throws:
NoResultException - if there is no result
NonUniqueResultException - if more than one result
IllegalStateException - if called for a Java Persistence query language UPDATE or DELETE statement
QueryTimeoutException - if the query execution exceeds the query timeout value set and only the statement is rolled back
TransactionRequiredException - if a lock mode has been set and there is no transaction
PessimisticLockException - if pessimistic locking fails and the transaction is rolled back
LockTimeoutException - if pessimistic locking fails and only the statement is rolled back
PersistenceException - if the query execution exceeds the query timeout value set and the transaction is rolled back
```